# What's the proper way to wait for a value in redux store before we execute

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm pretty new to redux react. I need to execute a few actions with a value in the redux store but I need to make sure it's set before I can use it. Here's the snippet of code. As the web application first loads, it needs to populate the councils variable. If it's not populated by the time the councils, it will throw an error.

```
const { dispatchUpdateNcId,dispatchUpdateSelectedCouncils,dispatchUpdateUnselectedCouncils, councils } = this.props;

    setTimeout(() => {
      const selectedCouncilId = Number(this.initialState.councilId);
      const newSelectedCouncil = councils.find(({ councilId }) => councilId === selectedCouncilId);
      const newSelected = [newSelectedCouncil];
      dispatchUpdateSelectedCouncils(newSelected);
      dispatchUpdateUnselectedCouncils(councils);
      dispatchUpdateNcId(selectedCouncilId);
    }, 10000)


...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ncBoundaries: state.metadata.ncGeojson,
  requestTypes: state.metadata.requestTypes,
  councils: state.metadata.councils,
  selectedNcId: state.filters.councilId,
  ncId: state.data.selectedNcId,
});
```

I'm currently using setTimeout() as a proof of concept but want to find the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Use `useEffect` or just an if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a simple `if` condition to not run the aforementioned code before `councils` is populated. The UI will be automatically re-render when the props is changed.

On the other hand, if you want to optimize performance. `useEffect` can be used as well. `useEffect` takes a callback function and a dep list where you can put `councils` as one dependency. Then the `useEffect` will make sure the callback is only executed when only the `councils` is changed. Other props changes wouldn't trigger this logic

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // the code will only be executed
}, [councils.length])
```